# Change the rotation of a 3D sphere to the exact opposite direction with GLUT

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, rotation, glut

I have a program i created with a rotating sphere (`glutWireSphere`) and i like to change the rotation to the exact opposite direction.

For example if it rotates slowly CW on the Y axis i want it to rotate CCW.

Here is the code i have so far:

```
float angle = 0.;

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0., -1.5, 0.);
    glRotatef(angle, 0.5, 1., 0.5);
    glColor3d(0, 0, 1);
    glutWireSphere(2, 25, 15);
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}

void idle() {
    angle += 0.2;
    if (angle > 360.) angle -= 360.;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void myinit() {
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-6., 6., -6., 6., -6., 6.);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10);
    glutCreateWindow("3d objects");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    myinit();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

To do what i just wrote i changed the values of the `X` `Y` & `Z` arguments inside the `glRotatef` function of the `display` function to `-0.5,-1.,-0.5` and i still get the exact same rotation.

I also tried to change the `idle` function to this (with the original `glRotatef` arguments):

```
void idle() {
    angle -= 0.2;
    if (angle < 0.) angle += 360.;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

And still, same rotation.

Am i missing something in my understanding here about the `glRotatef` function?

Comment: I think that your code is correct. The problem could be just an optic effect because using a wireframed sphere is difficult to see if it is rotating CW or CCW. Change the model for something without symmetry and you will see it.

Comment: `angle -= 0.2;` would do it. Flipping the axis is an option, but not at the same time as negative angles. Also slow down the rate of rotation to make sure you don't have an aliasing effect.

Answer (score 0):

As [JordiC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2287842/jordic) commented, since it was a perfect sphere, it was hard to see the true rotation of the shape.

I added a Cone inside of the Sphere and now I can clearly see the rotation is opposite.